# It is possible to create a node on drupal by using a java program?

Tags: drupal-7

I want to create a node on drupal by using a java program. Is it possible or not? If it is possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom module to provide an API for your

#### in simple situation these steps required

- your java app send request to drupal (your module) including **title** and **body** of node and an **authentication code**
- if your authentication code is valid your module programmatically create a node
- then module return success or fail response and your app process this response

this link help you to create a node in drupal in code  [Create a Node in Code](https://drupal.org/node/1388922)